# How can I get the secondary horizontal axis to the left and primary horizontal axis to the right in MS Excel 2013?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, charts

[image: This is a graph relating to civil engineering]

How can we get the secondary and primary horizontal axis to the left and right side respectively?

Comment: Are you referring to discharge?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to change your Chart Type to "Combo". From there you select the Chart Type you want. For the series that you want to belong to the Secondary Axis, check the appropriate checkbox on.

[image]

Comment: Yes. But that doesn't solve the problem of separation. The graph is separated in to two parts. One with depth on the right and rip-rap diameter (not seen in the picture) to the left. I want to know how that can be achieved.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't helpful

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've assigned one or more series to the secondary axes.

If your chart has a secondary Y axis and no secondary X axis, add the secondary X axis first. You can do this by clicking the plus icon next to the chart in Excel 2013-2016 and checking the Secondary Axis box, or using the buttons on the Chart Tools > Layout tab in Excel 2007-2010.

Select the primary X axis (probably on the bottom of the chart) and press Ctrl+1 to open the Format Axis dialog or task pane. Under Vertical Axis Crosses At, select Maximum. Then select the secondary X axis (probably on the top of the chart) and press Ctrl+1 to open the Format Axis dialog or task pane. Under Vertical Axis Crosses At, select Automatic, and it will pick zero.